# Get specific list of collection from a mongo DB collection

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, collections

I have  a collection in mongo DB with document consisting of movies ,series and product details . Format as below :
{
productname,
productid ,
movies :
[{movie1},{movie2} ] ,
series:
[{series1},{series2} ]
}
I want to get only movies with a product id . Currently able to apply filter by product id and get entire document but the document will contain even series . How can i restrict to get only movies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the projection option from the find statement:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

```
db.collection.find({productid},{series:0})
```